# Turn-Based-Strategy Game - Where to Store User State

Tags: model-view-controller

I'm writing a turn-based strategy game. Each player in the game has a team of units which can be individually controlled. On a user's turn, the game currently follows a pretty constant sequence of events:

Select a unit -> Move the selected unit -> Issue a command -> Confirm

I could implement this by creating a game class that keeps track of which of these stages the player is in and providing methods to move from one stage to the next, like this:

```
interface TeamCommander {
    public void select(Coordinate where);

    public void move(Coordinate to);

    public void sendCommand(String command);

    public void execute();
}
```

However, that would allow the possibility of a method being called at the wrong time (for example, calling `move()` before calling `select()`), and I would like to avoid that. So I currently have it implemented statelessly, like this:

```
interface UnitSelector {
    public UnitMover select(Coordinate where);
}

interface UnitMover {
    public UnitCommander move(Coordinate to);
}

interface UnitCommander {
    public CommandExecutor sendCommand(String command);
}

interface CommandExecutor {
    public void execute();
}
```

However, I'm having difficulty presenting this information to the user. Since this is stateless, the game model does not store any information about what the user is currently doing, and thus the view can't query the model about it. I could store some state in the GUI, but that would be bad form. So, my question is: does anyone have an idea about how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

First, there's something I'm not getting here: You have to be storing persistent state *somewhere*, even if it is only in the View / GUI. Without persistent state you cannot have a game. I'm guessing you're using either ASP or PHP; if so, use sessions to track state.

Secondly, build your state logic into that so it is known where in the input sequence you are for each player / each unit in that player's team. Don't try to get fancy with it. B requires A, C requires B and so on. While you're writing it, just give yourself a scaffold by throwing exceptions if the call order comes up incorrect (which you should be checking on every user input as I assume this is an event driven rather than loop-driven game), and debug it from there.

---

As an aside: I get suspicious when I see interfaces with a single method as in your second example above. An interface typically informs of there being a unique *SET* of functionalities which *different* classes each fulfill -- unless you are trying to construct multiple different classes which use slightly different sets of individual method signatures, don't do what you're doing there. It is all fine and good to say "code to an interface and not an implementation", but you need to first take the top down approach, saying, "How does my ultimate client code (in your root game logic class or method) need to call for such-and-such to occur?" and keep asking that question up the call stack (i.e. at each subsequent sub-call codepoint). If you try to build it from the bottom up, you will end up with the confusing and unnecessarily complicated code I see there. The only other exception to this which I see on a regular basis is the command pattern, and that is generally intended to look like

```
void execute();
```

or

```
void execute(Object data);
```

...But typically *not* a whole slew of slightly different method signatures (again possible, but unlikely). My gut feeling comes from my experience with such constructs in that they usually don't make sense and you end up completely refactoring code that uses them.